# What is the story on $variable->something in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I've seen this used a lot, especially with SimpleXML.

Is this:

```
$row->unixtime
```

simply the same as doing this???

```
$row[unixtime]
```

What is this called, why/how should it be used?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Object Oriented Programming with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301606/how-can-i-practice-better-object-oriented-programming)

```
$row->unixtime
```

$row is an object. unixtime is a property of that object.

```
$row[unixtime] // I hope you meant $row['unixtime'];
```

$row is an (associate) array. unixtime is a key in that array.

Asking 'What Objects are' is a bit vague.

- [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (Wikipedia)
- [How can I practice better object-oriented programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301606/how-can-i-practice-better-object-oriented-programming)
- [Pitfalls of Object oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145983/pitfalls-of-object-oriented-programming)
- [When is Object Oriented not the correct solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246808/when-is-object-oriented-not-the-correct-solution)
- [Learning object oriented thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157847/learning-object-oriented-thinking)

Getting started with OOP is not a trivial task. It takes a good while to learn the syntax and nuances, some more time to understand the advantages, and years(arguably) to actually use it effectively.

Answer (score 10):

It's totally different.

The first one, `$row->unixtime` means that you are accessing the public variable `$unixtime` of the object/instance of class `$row`. This is **Object Oriented Programming**.

Example:

```
class example{
  public $unixtime = 1234567890;
}

$row = new example();
echo $row->unixtime; // echos 1234567890
```

The second one, is to get the key `'unixtime'` of the array `$row`. This is called **Associative Array**. Example:

```
$row = array(
          'unixtime' => 1234567890
       );
echo $row['unixtime']; // echos 1234567890
```

You can easily convert between objects and arrays by using the `(array)` and `(object)` casts. Example:

```
$row = array(
          'unixtime' => 1234567890
       );
$row = (object)$row;
echo $row->unixtime; // echos 1234567890
```

*Off-topic: I actually missed out the unix epoch time 1234567890 in February.*

Answer (score 6):

No, they're not the same. It's about [object oriented programming](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_Object_Oriented_Programming).

`->` indicates accessing an object member. For example:

```
class Test {
  public $foo;
  public $blah;
}

$test = new Test;
$test->foo = 'testing';
```

`[]` is an array access operator, used by true arrays. Objects can also use it if they implement the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/kr/class.arrayaccess.php) interface:

```
class Test2 implements ArrayAccess {
  private $foo = array();

  public function offsetGet($index) { return $this->foo[$index]; }
  // rest of interface
}

$test2 = new Test2
$test2['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 3):

To make your answer short and sweet...

```
$row->unixtime
```

This is an **object**

```
$row[unixtime]
```

This is an **array**

Answer (score 1):

It's likely another idiom pulled from [the C language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), which is actually what PHP is written in. Many of PHP's features, syntax, and operators, and even many of PHP's native functions, have their roots in C.